# Getting Error when trying to extend ASP.NET Panel control

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I am trying to extend `System.Web.UI.WebControl.Panel` control. Below is my .cs code.

```
namespace XControls
{
    public class VisibilityChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public bool Visible { get; private set; }
        public VisibilityChangedEventArgs(bool visibility)
        {
            Visible = visibility;
        }
    }

public class XPanel : Panel
{
    public EventHandler VisibleChanged;

    public override bool Visible
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Visible;
        }

        set
        {
            base.Visible = value;
            OnVisibleChanged();
        }
    }

    protected void OnVisibleChanged()
    {
        if (VisibleChanged != null)
            VisibleChanged(this, new VisibilityChangedEventArgs(Visible));
    }
    }
}
```

And in `default.aspx` file first I register my XPanel.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="xc" Namespace="XControls" %>
```

And down in code try to use like this.

```
<xc:XPanel runat="server" id="xp">
            Hello XPanel
 </xc:XPanel>
```

But When I try to run this in browser I get an error:
**Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag 'xc:XPanel'.**

So what is the problem? 
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add assembly name as well when you register your control.

```
   <%@ Register TagPrefix="xc" Namespace="WebApplication1" Assembly="WebApplication1" %>
```